# Android NDK for Objective C

Tags: android-ndk

I want access Objective C code by using Android NDK,is it possible?
Is there any way to access existing Objective C code.

Comment: Note that even if you get Objective C to compile, none of the Cocoa support classes (`NSString`, `NSArray`, etc.) would port to Android. They're Apple's proprietary. That's why when people build a shared mobile app core, they do it in C or C++ that's compatible with both for sure.

Comment: CoreFoundation is [OSS](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744/)

Comment: Apportable implements Foundation on top of the OSS CoreFoundation

Answer (score 3):

Now, yes!

**UPDATE**: Apportable is dead!

Try [Apportable SDK](http://www.apportable.com) or [Crystax SDK](http://www.crystax.net) . Both is based on Android NDK.

Answer (score 2):

It is really possible now. First, Google has substitute llvm clang tool chain for GCC. Clang supports modern Objective-C syntax. Second, GNUstep has officially released the buid tools for Android. Please check this GitHub: https://github.com/gnustep/tools-android

I have tried this and it works. You may refer my blog, although it is written in Chinese: https://www.jianshu.com/p/97f6d948f115