# run objective-c static library on Android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, static-libraries, .a

How I can run objective-c static library ".a" with iOS dependencies for Android application?
Details:
We have iOS project with objective-c framework (customized and haven't analogs on java). It should run on android.
Android NDK can't run with iOS dependencies - it is a main problem

Comment: What makes you think this is at all possible? You should have written a C/C++ framework to be used both by iOS and Android instead.

Comment: I hava a .h and .cpp files of this framework. We are should depends on this libraries. Or we can create static ".a" library for use them. Question: How?

Comment: Apportable has been closed. Please refer this thread to solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477768/android-ndk-for-objective-c/55891453#55891453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly add an objective c library to an android project but you can try this tool: http://www.apportable.com that lets you run objective c code on android.

Comment: It's tool for convert to apk file.

Comment: Yes and it is the only way to use objective c code to android. As said above you cannot direct link objective-c libraries to android projects. Regarding the option, it is an option as the option you want does not exist (and it cannot technically exist as android does not "understand" objective-c code. You can move to C/C++ for your library if you like.

Comment: yes, I hava a .h and .cpp files of this framework. But thay have a dependencies on iOS libraries - its a main problem. Maybe excist some tool with ios libraries

Comment: as said, you cannot. You have to write the whole library using just c/c++ headers that run on android too.

Comment: Apportable has gone out of business.

Answer (score 0):

You won’t be able to take a static library built for iOS and directly use it on Android.

However, if your library consists of Objective C code using mainly the Foundation or CoreFoundation frameworks, you can use the [GNUstep Android toolchain](https://github.com/gnustep/tools-android) to compile the library for Android.

Note that this will not work if your library uses other iOS-specific frameworks like UIKit.