# Is is possible to write app for iOS and move object-c code into Android?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

Today I was speaking with PM. He said that the best way to solve problem "The same app working on iOS and Android" is to write object-c code for iOS and then use **the same code** in Android app (https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). That approach (in his opinion) will give us **DRY** effect (have one code to maintain).

I was so shocked that I almost didn't say anything to it. But after some time I think about it and found some problems:

1. C++ != Object-C. It is possible to add o-c code as c++ code in Android?
2. (Let say that #1 is possible) How can I do layouts, activities, ect. in c++ for Android?
3. Also when we should / should not use Android NDK?

Comment: Its not possible but you can use Phonegap or titanium kind of language to develop a mobile application that can run same across the platform.

Comment: I think he confused c with obj-c. You may want to look into a cross platform solution for this. There are many free and commercial products available to achieve this.

Comment: 1.) Never trust a PM, they have no clue :P :)(Just kidding) 2.) This case may be he does, checkout:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477768/android-ndk-for-objective-c.

Comment: Love it when project managers try and use developer speak, and get it soo wrong. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no it's not possible. However http://www.apportable.com

Claims to enable you to compile your iOS app for Android - thus enabling you to use all of the code in your iPhone app.

However it doesn't work with everyframe work but does have hooks in to the Android SDK so you can still access those components. Worth looking at, and having a play with. I have but only half-heartly and you'd have to build the iOS app from the outset with the plan to use http://www.apportable.com as like I said it doesn't currently support all ios sdks and you'd need to work around that.

But that should answer your question.

As of 2016 app portable is no longer an option [more info](https://venturebeat.com/2016/08/18/google-secretly-acqui-hired-mobile-app-development-startup-apportable/) it appears Google killed the dream.

Comment: Apportable has gone out of business.

Comment: Updated it, didn't even cross my mind this question would still be of interest in 2019 ;)

Comment: Thanks – it is to some people. :) As an alternative to Apportable you can now also use the [GNUstep Android toolchain](https://github.com/gnustep/tools-android) for similar purposes (see also my separate answer below).

Comment: I saw that, but TBH at that point you'd probably be better using ReactNative or something else.

Comment: True, except maybe if you have a large existing code base using Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

Objective C code will not compile with the NDK. But check out http://www.apportable.com/ it's a library that allows you to write code for Android in Objective-C. That could be what your boss was talking about.

Comment: Does this support other things than games? i.e.: normal app connecting to server via HTTP (REST)?

Answer (score 1):

1. C++ < Objective-c. Objective-c is built on top of a C compiler ... Just name the files with *.mm and write c/c++ code. Basically what you could do is write functions that you want to share across platforms in c++ and use them in an Android project via JNI wrappers.
2. You can not share code which uses ios system Frameworks (UIKit, CFNetwork, ...) directly.

If you want to write code for whole apps once, you could give it a shot with apportable.com, like others have pointed out.

Comment: Yep, Apportable id built on top of the Android SDK (#1) and implements a bunch of iOS System Frameworks(#2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GNUstep Android toolchain](https://github.com/gnustep/tools-android) to use model code based on Foundation and CoreFoundation in an Android app, and then write a new UI layer that interacts with the Objective C model via native NDK calls on top of that (e.g. in Android Studio).